# Custom Resolution not Persisting Across Reboots

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

I have a problem regarding setting a custom resolution on my built-in display for my laptop. My desired resolution is `1600x900`. It's not shown in the Display Settings in Ubuntu 16.04, but after running the following,

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync and
sudo xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1600x900_60.00"
```

the resolution is added to Displays Settings and I can apply it. Additionally, I put the 2 commands at the end of my `~/.profile` file, as [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/) tutorial recommended. The problem is that it does not persist after a restart, rather I get an error: "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors".

Additionally, I lack the `/etc/gdm/init/Default` file to place these commands in that script.

Comment: It looks like the `xrandr` commands aren't being executed properly. If you're going to add them to your `~/.profile`, make sure you get rid of the `sudo`s in front of them.

Comment: You are right, i have paste the commands with the 'sudo' in front of them. After removing 'sudo' everything works fine after restart. Thanks And have a nice day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Posting this as an answer from the comments)

The lines in `~/.profile` should not be prepended with `sudo`. Thus, the lines to be appended should be as such:

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync and
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1600x900_60.00"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 16.04 still uses `lightdm` (I think it does) you can set up a script to do your monitor settings.

Modify `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to add the following options:

display-setup-script > calls your "xrandr scriptname.sh" before the login screen appears

session-setup-script > calls your "xrandr scriptname.sh" before the user desktop session starts

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
# for your login screen, e.g. LightDM (Ubuntu 11.10) or GDM (11.04 or earlier)
display-setup-script=[your xrandr script goes here]
# for your desktop session (I didn't do this one)
session-setup-script=[your xrandr script goes here]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm sure it'll work.  nixpower found the problem, I have accidentally inserted the 'sudo' command in front of the two 'xrandr' commands, in the ~/.profile file. After removing them everything works. After restart the resolution remains the custom one. Thanks and have a nice day!